# Web Site project structure : Efficiently using stylesheets

Tags: html, css, structure, project

I am currently building a website and need a header and a footer to repeat on every page and I was just wondering, what is the best way to structure my project. Would it be a great idea to use a "main" stylesheet to format the header and footer and then use secondary stylesheets to format whatever content I want in the other pages' main sections?

Feel free to tell me if my question does not fall in the scope of SO but I really couldn't find my anwser anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can use php, then have an includes folder with the header and footer files and include them in every page, the external style sheet will be able to contain all styling for the header, footer and other paage elements. If you can't use php, then you might try server side includes and use the .shtml file extension. Either way - the style sheet can cope with all included files. Just use the correct selectors, id's and classes to target the elements.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know PHP could be use to do that... In fact I don't know PHP at all but I'm gonna get into it right now! :)

Comment: You're welcome. You should do some reading on php includes as well as the differences betwee "include" and "require", but in general - you save your header and footer files as separate files in the includes folder and then call them as follows: <?php include 'includes/header.php';?>. When the page is rendered they are placed into hte page structure. The benefit of doing it this way is that if you have to make changes to hte content of the header or footer files, ythen you just make the changes to the one file and the changes are passed to all the pages that the included files are called into.

Comment: This in fact looks pretty cool. Any good ressources I could use other than the official doc to learn PHP?

Comment: Google is your friend! I have books that i used when i was studying, but to start with try "http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp" - but just note that some people do not like w3 as a learning resource. Its best to read from a variety of sources and learn by trial and error. Just note that if you are using a local server you will need to set up XAMPP or similar to be able to view your files.and then the url to see them in browser will be similar to "http://localhost/xampp/mywebsite/index.php"

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir! :)